# How to get scaled Bitmap from ImageView

Tags: android

I am having a `Activity` which has a custom `ImageView` defined in the XML for Pinch Zoom functionality on an image. Now, my problem is that I want to fetch the scaled `Bitmap` from the Pinch Zoom functionality. For example if the user peforms zooming on the Image, then I want to store the exact size and the position of the Image as Bitmap.

This is my custom ImageView declared in XML.

```
<com.cam.view.PinchZoom_ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/gallery_selected_image_view"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/icon"
  android:scaleType="center"
 />
```

**UPDATE:**

I am trying the below code to get the scaled Image, but It returns a Blank Bitmap.

```
        pinchZoom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        pinchZoom.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                    MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        pinchZoom.layout(0, 0, pinchZoom.getMeasuredWidth(), pinchZoom.getMeasuredHeight());
        pinchZoom.buildDrawingCache(true);
        Bitmap_gallery_Item = Bitmap.createBitmap(pinchZoom.getDrawingCache());
        pinchZoom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, finally I can't believe that it was just a one line code. I finally succeeded using the `matrix`. The solution is very simple that I was storing the `translation and scaling` of the Image in a matrix. So, I declared that final `matrix` as `public static` and used that matrix to create draw a Bitmap on canvas.

```
        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
        background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background, width, height, true);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(foreground, PinchZoom_ImageView.matrix, null);
```

As you can see here `PinchZoom_ImageView.matrix`. It is a `matrix` that contains my final position of the scaled and translated image which I had declared as `public static`.

Comment: @Lalit Poptani - Looks like this works only if the ImageView matrix is explicitly set.  Would be great to have a way that just extracts a bitmap as currently displayed regardless of the scale type.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `scaleType="fitxy"` then you can use a scaling factor to enlarge or shrink the width/height of the ImageView - It also means that you can pull back the exact height/width of the image because it has the same dimensions as it's container.

HTH

Comment: I am not having fitxy buddy, my Image is movable and also it allows zooming as well, so I want to store the Bitmap after translation as well as scaling of the Image. Thanks

Comment: Ok - I don't know what the situation is but could you not make the image movable and zooming by implementing the ImageView as above?

Comment: By above means are you saying that by using scaleType="fitxy"?.

Comment: Yeah, by using the ImageView AS the image.

Comment: Ok, i'll assume there is a reason for that and not suggest to just change it :)

Answer (score 0):

This post includes Cropping the Image from the Gallery and allows user to crop the Image and save the cropped Image and Shows in ImageView.

Seems it will help you some extends

[Image Crop and show cropped Image in View](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)

Comment: @Lalit Poptani  Okay da machan